# changing project package structure in grails

Tags: grails, package

We are moving our project code internally into new packages(controllers, services, gsps). So all imports in file will change,
Is there an auto refactoring for this available in grails or do we need to do the changes manually?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the re-factoring feature of the IDE you are using. I have used Eclipse(STS) and IntellijIdea and both have this feature of re-factoring.

You need to Right click the package -> Refactoring -> Rename

Once you do the rename all the references to your package will be changed automatically.

Not sure which IDE you are using but out of the two mentioned, STS has a better refactoring feature.

Comment: Netbeans also has this re-factoring feature. Look at following link. It shous it for variable but work in same way for package as well.            http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring